# Javascript links open in same page

Tags: javascript

How do i use Javascript to load content on the same page without reloading the entire page,

Answer (score 1):

what you are looking for is called [AJAX](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&q=javascript+ajax+tutorial&meta=&aq=0&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=javascript+ajax&gs_rfai=&fp=35e96e80585d6444) - and there are lots of tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use the jQuery append method: http://api.jquery.com/append/ or the jQuery text method: http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Assuming you are not grabbing that content from another location, in which case you would want to use AJAX as oezi mentions.